# Balanced equation for the hydration of cyclohexene to synthesise cyclohexanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, stoichiometry

I'm trying to determine the full balanced equation for a hydration of cyclohexene to synthesise cyclohexanol using concentrated sulfuric acid as catalyst and distillation as the extraction method. I'm not quite sure if I have done the balancing right, and if the notation is correct.

Here is my attempt:

$$\ce{C6H10 ->[][{\ce{H2SO4}}] C6H12O4S ->[][{\ce{H2O}\, + heat}] C6H13O^+ + HSO4^- <->[\ce{H2O}] C6H12O + H3O+}$$

Comment: Why is the sulfate bonded with the cyclohexyl ring? This should just be a protonation. Generally, in organic chemistry, plain old balanced reactions are of limited use. You almost always want to draw out an arrow pushing mechanism instead.

Comment: @Zhe I know cyclohexyl hydrogen sulfate is an intermediate compound of the reaction which is why I included it here.

Comment: Except it's not. This is a classic $S_{\mathrm{N}}1$ reaction. The hydrogen sulfate might be coupled to the cation as an ion pair, but you're really not going to bond them.